# How can I make my transparent div backgrounds appear solid on IE6,7,8

Tags: html, css

I am building a website and it looks like I want it too on all browsers except old IE versions. Transparent div backgrounds are a big part of my site and I would like to know if there is some way you can make it so IE6 will see: rgba (0,0,0,0.6) and change it to #000000.

If you would like to see what I mean [here](http://www.surefitmeasures1.appspot.com/Family/family.html)'s the site.

Answer (score 2):

Old versions of browsers will default to what they do understand.

```
body {
  background: #000;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
}
```

Will be transparent in modern browsers and fall back to plain old `#000` for old version of IE, etc.

Answer (score 2):

just declare a fallback like this:

```
div {
   background: #000000; /* the fallback */
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); 
}
```

browsers that don't know rgba (like IE6) won't understand the second line, ignore it and use the first declaration instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my browser independent background transparency

```
.transparent {
 background:rgb(0,33,66);
 background:rgba(0,33,66,0.7);
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(
  startColorstr=#19FFFFFF,endColorstr=#19FFFFFF);
 -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(
  startColorstr=#19FFFFFF,endColorstr=#19FFFFFF)";
}
```

line 1 set's a solid color 0,33,66 on browser that does not support transparency

line 2 set's the same color at 70% alpha

The last two lines are IE hacks for their early support of transparency,  They somehow apply the .7 alpha value from the rgba.

Good luck